# Zooming towards center of Camera on 2d Plane

Tags: c++, geometry, 2d, sfml

Once again, camera zooming on a 2D-Plane. I searched a lot and know that there are similar questions, but I am obviously way too stupid to apply what I was able to find.

Basically I multiply the distance of all elements to the origin by `mouseDelta`, which is a `double` between 0.5 and 1. works fine for all elements, but since the anchor of the camera (`camX`, `camY`) are the upper left corner of the camera, the objects in the focus of the cam change their position in relation to the focus. I want to scroll "towards" the focus. Here is what I got, but it behaves really weird:

camX and camY, as mentioned, are the coordinates for the upper left of the cam.
mouseDelta is the zoom-level thats stored globally and is changed by each wheel-event.
screenX is the width of the screen/window (fullscreen anyways)
screenY is the height of the screen/window

```
if (newEvent.type == sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved) //zoom
{

    mouseDelta += ((double)newEvent.mouseWheel.delta)/20;
    if (mouseDelta > 1) { mouseDelta = 1; }
    else if (mouseDelta < 0.5) { mouseDelta = 0.5; }

    //resize graphics
    for (int i = 0; i < core->universe->world->nodes.size(); i++) {
        core->universe->world->nodes.at(i).pic->setSize(mouseDelta);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < core->universe->world->links.size(); i++) {
        core->universe->world->links.at(i).pic->setSize(mouseDelta);
    }

    camX = (camX + screenX/2) - (camX + screenX/2)*mouseDelta;
    camY = (camY + screenY/2) - (camY + screenY/2)*mouseDelta;
}
```

Comment: Don't be afraid to use matrix math.

Comment: this might have what you need
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-view.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zooming graphics based on current mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262282/zooming-graphics-based-on-current-mouse-position)

Comment: see the duplicate QA in my answer is what you need (it is in C++) and use screen center instead of mouse position.