# Scaling owner-draw window around mouse point

Tags: c#, c++, .net, algorithm, graphics

I have an owner-draw PictureBox (`picGrid`) and I want to allow the user to zoom using the mouse wheel. That part is easy. But I want to automatically scroll such that the logical point under the mouse is *still* the logical point under the mouse after the zoom.

Here's what I have so far. It almost works but is just not right. `XScroll` and `YScroll` are my scroll positions and will be used to set the scroll bar (in addition to offset the image).

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the current zoom percent.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="percent">The percent that the zoom should be set (100 == 1:1 scaling).</param>
/// <param name="x">X coordinate of the mouse in pixels.</param>
/// <param name="y">Y coordinate of the mouse in pixels.</param>
public void SetZoom(int percent, int x, int y)
{
    // If needed, this method translates mouse coordinate to logical coordinates
    // but doesn't appear to be needed here.
    //TranslateCoordinates(ref x, ref y);

    // Calculate new scale (1.0f == 1:1 scaling)
    float newDrawScale = (float)percent / 100;

    // Enforce zoom limits
    if (newDrawScale < 0.1f)
        newDrawScale = 0.1f;
    else if (newDrawScale > 1500.0f)
        newDrawScale = 1500.0f;

    // Set new zoom (if it's changed)
    if (newDrawScale != DrawScale)
    {
        DrawScale = newDrawScale;

        // *** Here's the part that isn't right ***

        // Scroll to keep same logical point under mouse
        float delta = (DrawScale - 1f);
        XScroll = (x * delta);
        YScroll = (y * delta);

        // Reflect change in scrollbars
        UpdateScrollbars();

        // Redraw content
        picGrid.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

How can I calculate the new scroll position so that the same logical point remains under the mouse pointer after the zoom?

Comment: see [Zooming graphics based on current mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269366/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre: Thanks. I spent a lot of time looking at that answer (which I see is yours). Some things were confusing to me. For example, the variable names were not very descriptive. Also, your `scr2obj()` and `obj2scr()` methods add `x0`,`y0` where I needed to subtract them, and subtracted them where I needed to add them. In addition, I don't know what *gfx objects* are and so I didn't understand the two versions of the code. However, I was finally able to come up with a working solution based on your approach. I appreciate it. I've posted my working code in case anyone else can benefit.

Comment: Yep there are more ways how to transform between screen and world as you saw its not just positive/negative `offset`, its also if you apply `offset` before or after `zoom`, If the `zoom` is direct scale or reciproc like `1/zoom` these gives you `2^3=8` combinations of equation. If you add transform matrices there are more possible notations on top of all this  making this a mess for rookies that just copy paste code without knowing what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work through this. This is what I came up with. (Note that `XOffset` and `YOffset` are in screen coordinates to match the scrollbars.)

```
public void SetZoom(int percent, int x, int y)
{
    // Calculate new scale (100% == 1:1)
    float newDrawScale = (float)percent / 100;

    // See if scale has changed
    if (newDrawScale != DrawScale)
    {
        // Update scale and adjust offsets
        ScreenToWorld(x, y, out float logicalX, out float logicalY);
        DrawScale = newDrawScale;
        WorldToScreen(logicalX, logicalY, out float screenX, out float screenY);
        XOffset += (screenX - x);
        YOffset += (screenY - y);

        // Update scrollbars and redraw
        UpdateScrollbars();
        picGrid.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void WorldToScreen(float srcX, float srcY, out float destX, out float destY)
{
    destX = (srcX * DrawScale) - XOffset;
    destY = (srcY * DrawScale) - YOffset;
}

private void ScreenToWorld(float srcX, float srcY, out float destX, out float destY)
{
    destX = (srcX + XOffset) / DrawScale;
    destY = (srcY + YOffset) / DrawScale;
}
```